# Intro.js doesn't skip over hidden element

Tags: php, jquery, intro.js

I been working with `Intro.js` for a week now and found out that it doesn't skip over hidden elements:

```
for (var i = 0, elmsLength = allIntroSteps.length; i < elmsLength; i++) {
        var currentElement = allIntroSteps[i];

        //alert(( jQuery(currentElement).is(':visible') ));
        // skip hidden elements
        /*if (jQuery(currentElement).is(':visible') == true) {
          continue;
        }*/

        if (currentElement.style.display == 'none') {
          continue;
        }

        var step = parseInt(currentElement.getAttribute('data-step'), 10);

        if (step > 0) {
          introItems[step - 1] = {
            element: currentElement,
            intro: currentElement.getAttribute('data-intro'),
            step: parseInt(currentElement.getAttribute('data-step'), 10),
            tooltipClass: currentElement.getAttribute('data-tooltipClass'),
            highlightClass: currentElement.getAttribute('data-highlightClass'),
            position: currentElement.getAttribute('data-position') || this._options.tooltipPosition
          };
        }
      }
```

it still doesn't work.

anyone know what is the real issue ? please help

Comment: This depends on the markup as well as the styles. You should provide a test-setup where this problem can be reproduced.

Comment: you need to provide more code, where's your loop?

Comment: @billyonecan I just updated please have a look

Comment: What @billyonecan says in his post is crucial. The `continue` keyword is used to *skip* the current iteration but *continue* the looping. (Compare with `break` that *skips* the current iteration and then *break* out of the loop, i.e. stop the loop.)

Comment: hey, Intro.js's author is here. I'm fixing it for the next version. sorry about that.

Comment: @Afshin Mehrabani When will it be ready? can u give me quick solution please

Comment: @TanvirAlam it will be ready in two weeks. you can use `billyonecan`'s solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting `currentElement.style.display` will only work if you've declared the style inline. It won't work if you're setting it via a css rule.

```
<div style="display: none;"> // el.style.display = 'none'
<div class="ruleWithDisplayNone"> // el.style.display = ''
```

The reason your jQuery approach won't work is because your condition is checking the opposite of what you want. If you want to skip over hidden elements, you want to `continue` when the element **isn't** visible.

```
if (! jQuery(currentElement).is(':visible')) {
    continue;
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foh4mb8h/)

Comment: @billyonecam its not working. if (! jQuery(currentElement).is(':visible')) { and if ( jQuery(currentElement).is(':visible') == false) {

still it doesn't work. 

I am not setting it via CSS but JQUERY .hide()